# How to assign a string to an empty string variable

Tags: python

```
grade=""
name=[]
courseworkMark=[]
examMark=[]

file=open("Test Marks.csv","r")

for line in file:
    LineFromFile=(line.strip())
    pupilName,pupilCoursework,pupilExam=LineFromFile.split(",")

    name.append(str(pupilName))
    courseworkMark.append(int(pupilCoursework))
    examMark.append(int(pupilExam))

file.close
                
#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def calculatePercentage(courseworkMark, examMark):
    Percentage = round(((courseworkMark[index]+examMark[index])/160)*100)
    return Percentage

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def calculateGrade(Percentage):
    if Percentage >= 70:
        #print("Your grade is an A")
        grade=="A"
    elif Percentage >=60 and Percentage <=69:
        #print("Your grade is a B")
        grade=="B"
    elif Percentage >=50 and Percentage <=59:
        #print("Your grade is a C")
        grade=="C"
    elif Percentage >=45 and Percentage <=49:
        #print("Your grade is a D")
        grade=="D"
    else:
        #print("You have failed")
        grade=="Fail"

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def displayInformation(name,Percentage):
    print(name[index],"got",Percentage,"% in total which is a/an",grade)

#-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


for index in range (len(name)):
    Percentage = calculatePercentage(courseworkMark, examMark)
    Grade = calculateGrade(Percentage)
    displayInformation(name, Percentage)
```

Hi everyone, I am currently trying to assign another string to an already existing empty string variable however when I run the code, the value for grade is still empty as it is when first defined, I hope someone is able to help, many thanks

Comment: You're not assigning, you're *comparing*…

Comment: Write ```grade = "A"``` instead of making a comparison

Comment: The assignment operator is `=` not the `==`. So you need to write `grade="D"`

Comment: You need to do `return "A"` _or_ `grade = "A"` and add a `return grade` at the very end of `calculateGrade`.

Answer (score 2):

I see three problems.
You compare grade with strings instead of assigning: "==" instead of "="
You assign value to variable Grade, not grade.
calculateGrade returns nothing.